# Opening a .fit file in an ImageJ macro

Tags: macros, imagej

I'm looking to open a series of .fit files and re-save them as Jpegs in ImageJ using a macro. I'm a complete novice to code-writing in ImageJ so may have done something wrong. The error message I get coming up can be seen, along with my code, in the picture below:

[image]

I've double checked: the file is definitely in that location and I can still have ImageJ open it if I just double-click on it in the folder. Any ideas why this is going wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is a .fit file? I have never heard of that format before. Something tells me you don't mean the [.fit of fitness trackers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FIT).

Comment: Yes, you're right, not the .fit of fitness trackers! We're using it here as a format to save images in. I assumed it was a normal file extension but after doing a quick google, I can't seem to find much info on it. I'm now wondering if it's a file extension our in-house coders have put on themselves for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: for all "/" in the file address I replaced with "\\".